# Download and Extract Zip File in Android

Tags: android, download, unzip

My application is downloading zip file from the server and extract this zip file and save files into sd card but problem is if i am downloading 4-5 MB zip files and extract it, this is working good but if i am downloading 30-35 MB zip file this will give me error, sorry for my bad English communication.

The Below is my Code for Download & Unzip Zip File:-

```
public class UnzipManager {
    private static String BASE_FOLDER;

    public static Context localContext;
    public static String passurl;
    public static int count;
    public static Context context;
    /*
     * You can use this flag to check whether Unzippingthread is still running..
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadInProgress;
    /*
     * After unzipping using this flag ,you can check whether any low memory
     * exceptions Occurred or not..and alert user accordingly..
     */
    public static boolean isLowOnMemory;
    public static int i = 0;

    public static ZipEntry zipEntry;

    public static void startUnzipping(Context ctx, int c, String url) {
        context = ctx;
        count = c;
        /*
         * MAKE SURE THAT localContext VARIABLE HAS BEEN INITIALIZED BEFORE
         * INVOKING THIS METHOD.
         * 
         * ALSO MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SET "INTERNET" AND "NETWORK ACCESS STATE"
         * PERMISSIONS IN APPLICATION'S MANIFEST FILE.
         */
        Log.d("DEBUG", "In startUnzipping()");
        UnzipManager.BASE_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "samples";
        /*
         *
         */

        Log.d("DEBUG", "BASE_FOLDER:" + UnzipManager.BASE_FOLDER);
        UnzipManager.isLowOnMemory = false;
        // Start unzipping in a thread..which is safer
        // way to do high cost processes..
        passurl = url;
        new UnzipThread().start();
    }

    private static class UnzipThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UnzipManager.isDownloadInProgress = true;
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Unzipping----------------------------");
            URLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                /************************************************
                 * 
                 * IF you are unzipping a zipped file save under some URL in
                 * remote server
                 * **********************************************/
                URL finalUrl = new URL(passurl
                /* Url string where the zipped file is stored... */);
                urlConnection = finalUrl.openConnection();

                // Get the size of the ( zipped file's) inputstream from
                // server..
                int contentLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "urlConnection.getContentLength():"
                        + contentLength);
                /*****************************************************
                 * 
                 * YOU CAN GET INPUT STREAM OF A ZIPPED FILE FROM ASSETS FOLDER
                 * AS WELL..,IN THAT CASE JUST PASS THAT INPUTSTEAM OVER
                 * HERE...MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SET STREAM CONTENT LENGTH OF THE
                 * SAME..
                 * 
                 ******************************************************/
                ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream());
                /*
                 * Iterate over all the files and folders
                 */
                for (zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry(); zipEntry != null; zipEntry = zipInputStream
                        .getNextEntry()) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Extracting: " + zipEntry.getName() + "...");

                    /*
                     * Extracted file will be saved with same file name that in
                     * zipped folder.
                     */


                    String innerFileName = BASE_FOLDER + File.separator
                            + zipEntry.getName();
                    File innerFile = new File(innerFileName);

                    /*
                     * Checking for pre-existence of the file and taking
                     * necessary actions
                     */
                    if (innerFile.exists()) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG",
                                "The Entry already exits!, so deleting..");
                        innerFile.delete();
                    }

                    /*
                     * Checking for extracted entry for folder type..and taking
                     * necessary actions
                     */
                    if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "The Entry is a directory..");
                        innerFile.mkdirs();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "The Entry is a file..");
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                                innerFileName);
                        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

                        /*
                         * Get the buffered output stream..
                         */
                        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                outputStream, BUFFER_SIZE);
                        /*
                         * Write into the file's buffered output stream ,..
                         */
                        int count = 0;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                            bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                        /***********************************************
                         * IF YOU WANT TO TRACK NO OF FILES DOWNLOADED, HAVE A
                         * STATIC COUNTER VARIABLE, INITIALIZE IT IN
                         * startUnzipping() before calling startUnZipping(), AND
                         * INCREMENT THE COUNTER VARIABLE OVER HERE..LATER YOU
                         * CAN USE VALUE OF COUNTER VARIABLE TO CROSS VERIFY
                         * WHETHER ALL ZIPPED FILES PROPERLY UNZIPPED AND SAVED
                         * OR NOT.
                         * 
                         * ************************************************
                         */
                        /*
                         * Handle closing of output streams..
                         */
                        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                        bufferedOutputStream.close();
                    }
                    /*
                     * Finish the current zipEntry
                     */
                    zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                }
                /*
                 * Handle closing of input stream...
                 */
                zipInputStream.close();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "--------------------------------");
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Unzipping completed..");
                i = 1;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
                if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("No space left on device")) {
                    UnzipManager.isLowOnMemory = true;
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MainActivity.pd.dismiss();

            ((MainActivity)context).finish();       

            UnzipManager.isDownloadInProgress = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Logcat Error is:-

```
02-17 12:21:16.835: D/DEBUG(20562): Exception occured: /mnt/sdcard/samples/iPhone_zendura_Q4a/0.png (No such file or directory)
02-17 12:21:16.835: W/System.err(20562): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/samples/iPhone_zendura_Q4a/0.png (No such file or directory)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)
02-17 12:21:16.906: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.screens.UnzipManager$UnzipThread.run(UnzipManager.java:129)
```

Comment: This is really a great way to download and Extract the zips.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote an `IntentService` that dose both the things together with progress :

**Add following Service class to your Application (also declare it in your app's Manifest file) :**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

/**
 * Created by Vaibhav.Jani on 6/4/15.
 */
public class FileDownloadService extends IntentService {

    private static int STATUS_OK = 100;

    private static int STATUS_FAILED = 200;

    private static final String DOWNLOADER_RECEIVER = "downloader_receiver";

    private static final String DOWNLOAD_DETAILS = "download_details";

    private static final String DOWNLOAD_STARTED = "download_started";

    private static final String DOWNLOAD_FAILED = "download_failed";

    private static final String DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED = "download_completed";

    private static final String DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = "download_progress";

    public FileDownloadService() {

        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle == null
                || !bundle.containsKey(DOWNLOADER_RECEIVER)
                || !bundle.containsKey(DOWNLOAD_DETAILS)) {

            return;
        }

        ResultReceiver resultReceiver = bundle.getParcelable(DOWNLOADER_RECEIVER);

        DownloadRequest downloadDetails = bundle.getParcelable(DOWNLOAD_DETAILS);

        try {

            assert downloadDetails != null;
            URL url = new URL(downloadDetails.getServerFilePath());

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            Log.d("FileDownloaderService", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);
            downloadStarted(resultReceiver);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            String localPath = downloadDetails.getLocalFilePath();

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(localPath);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            int count;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                total += count;

                int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile);

                sendProgress(progress, resultReceiver);

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            if (downloadDetails.isRequiresUnzip()) {

                String unzipDestination = downloadDetails.getUnzipAtFilePath();

                if(unzipDestination == null){

                    File file = new File(localPath);

                    unzipDestination = file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
                }

                unzip(localPath, unzipDestination);
            }

            downloadCompleted(resultReceiver);

            if (downloadDetails.isDeleteZipAfterExtract()) {

                File file = new File(localPath);
                file.delete();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            downloadFailed(resultReceiver);
        }

    }

    public void sendProgress(int progress, ResultReceiver receiver) {

        Bundle progressBundle = new Bundle();
        progressBundle.putInt(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS, progress);
        receiver.send(STATUS_OK, progressBundle);
    }

    public void downloadStarted(ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {

        Bundle progressBundle = new Bundle();
        progressBundle.putBoolean(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_STARTED, true);
        resultReceiver.send(STATUS_OK, progressBundle);
    }

    public void downloadCompleted(ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {

        Bundle progressBundle = new Bundle();
        progressBundle.putBoolean(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED, true);
        resultReceiver.send(STATUS_OK, progressBundle);
    }

    public void downloadFailed(ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {

        Bundle progressBundle = new Bundle();
        progressBundle.putBoolean(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_FAILED, true);
        resultReceiver.send(STATUS_FAILED, progressBundle);
    }

    private void unzip(String zipFilePath, String unzipAtLocation) throws Exception {

        File archive = new File(zipFilePath);

        try {

            ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);

            for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {

                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();

                unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, unzipAtLocation);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Unzip zip", "Unzip exception", e);
        }
    }

    private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry, String outputDir) throws IOException {

        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
            return;
        }

        File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
        if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
        }

        Log.v("ZIP E", "Extracting: " + entry);

        InputStream zin = zipfile.getInputStream(entry);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zin);
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        try {

            //IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

            try {

                for (int c = inputStream.read(); c != -1; c = inputStream.read()) {
                    outputStream.write(c);
                }

            } finally {

                outputStream.close();
            }

        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private void createDir(File dir) {

        if (dir.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        Log.v("ZIP E", "Creating dir " + dir.getName());

        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Can not create dir " + dir);
        }
    }

    public static class FileDownloader extends ResultReceiver {

        private DownloadRequest downloadDetails;

        private OnDownloadStatusListener onDownloadStatusListener;

        public static FileDownloader getInstance(DownloadRequest downloadDetails, OnDownloadStatusListener downloadStatusListener) {

            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(handler);

            fileDownloader.downloadDetails = downloadDetails;

            fileDownloader.onDownloadStatusListener = downloadStatusListener;

            return fileDownloader;
        }

        public void download(Context context) {

            if (isOnline(context)) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FileDownloadService.class);
                intent.putExtra(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOADER_RECEIVER, this);
                intent.putExtra(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_DETAILS, downloadDetails);
                context.startService(intent);
            }
        }

        private FileDownloader(Handler handler) {

            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

            if (onDownloadStatusListener == null) {

                return;
            }

            if (resultCode == FileDownloadService.STATUS_OK) {

                if (resultData.containsKey(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_STARTED)
                        && resultData.getBoolean(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_STARTED)) {

                    onDownloadStatusListener.onDownloadStarted();

                } else if (resultData.containsKey(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED)
                        && resultData.getBoolean(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED)) {

                    onDownloadStatusListener.onDownloadCompleted();

                } else if (resultData.containsKey(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)) {

                    int progress = resultData.getInt(FileDownloadService.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                    onDownloadStatusListener.onDownloadProgress(progress);

                }

            } else if (resultCode == FileDownloadService.STATUS_FAILED) {

                onDownloadStatusListener.onDownloadFailed();
            }
        }

        public DownloadRequest getDownloadDetails() {

            return downloadDetails;
        }

        public void setDownloadDetails(DownloadRequest downloadDetails) {

            this.downloadDetails = downloadDetails;
        }

        public OnDownloadStatusListener getOnDownloadStatusListener() {

            return onDownloadStatusListener;
        }

        public void setOnDownloadStatusListener(OnDownloadStatusListener onDownloadStatusListener) {

            this.onDownloadStatusListener = onDownloadStatusListener;
        }

    }

    public static interface OnDownloadStatusListener {

        void onDownloadStarted();

        void onDownloadCompleted();

        void onDownloadFailed();

        void onDownloadProgress(int progress);

    }

    public static class DownloadRequest implements Parcelable {

        private String tag;

        private boolean requiresUnzip;

        private String serverFilePath;

        private String localFilePath;

        private String unzipAtFilePath;

        private boolean deleteZipAfterExtract = true;

        public DownloadRequest(String serverFilePath, String localPath) {

            this.serverFilePath = serverFilePath;

            this.localFilePath = localPath;

            this.requiresUnzip = requiresUnzip;
        }

        protected DownloadRequest(Parcel in) {

            requiresUnzip = in.readByte() != 0x00;
            serverFilePath = in.readString();
            localFilePath = in.readString();
            unzipAtFilePath = in.readString();
            deleteZipAfterExtract = in.readByte() != 0x00;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

            dest.writeByte((byte) (requiresUnzip ? 0x01 : 0x00));
            dest.writeString(serverFilePath);
            dest.writeString(localFilePath);
            dest.writeString(unzipAtFilePath);
            dest.writeByte((byte) (deleteZipAfterExtract ? 0x01 : 0x00));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<DownloadRequest> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DownloadRequest>() {

            @Override
            public DownloadRequest createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

                return new DownloadRequest(in);
            }

            @Override
            public DownloadRequest[] newArray(int size) {

                return new DownloadRequest[size];
            }
        };

        public boolean isRequiresUnzip() {

            return requiresUnzip;
        }

        public void setRequiresUnzip(boolean requiresUnzip) {

            this.requiresUnzip = requiresUnzip;
        }

        public String getServerFilePath() {

            return serverFilePath;
        }

        public void setServerFilePath(String serverFilePath) {

            this.serverFilePath = serverFilePath;
        }

        public String getLocalFilePath() {

            return localFilePath;
        }

        public void setLocalFilePath(String localFilePath) {

            this.localFilePath = localFilePath;
        }

        public static Creator<DownloadRequest> getCreator() {

            return CREATOR;
        }

        public String getUnzipAtFilePath() {
            return unzipAtFilePath;
        }

        public void setUnzipAtFilePath(String unzipAtFilePath) {
            this.unzipAtFilePath = unzipAtFilePath;
        }

        public String getTag() {
            return tag;
        }

        public void setTag(String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }

        public boolean isDeleteZipAfterExtract() {
            return deleteZipAfterExtract;
        }

        public void setDeleteZipAfterExtract(boolean deleteZipAfterExtract) {
            this.deleteZipAfterExtract = deleteZipAfterExtract;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null
                && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Sample use case :

```
String serverFilePath = "http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/peace_problem.ZIP";

String path = FileUtils.getDataDir(context).getAbsolutePath();

String fileName = "sample_download";
File file = new File(path, fileName);

String localPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
String unzipPath = FileUtils.getDataDir(context, "ExtractLoc").getAbsolutePath();

FileDownloadService.DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new FileDownloadService.DownloadRequest(serverFilePath, localPath);
downloadRequest.setRequiresUnzip(true);
downloadRequest.setDeleteZipAfterExtract(false);
downloadRequest.setUnzipAtFilePath(unzipPath);

FileDownloadService.OnDownloadStatusListener listener = new FileDownloadService.OnDownloadStatusListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadCompleted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadProgress(int progress) {
    }
};

FileDownloadService.FileDownloader downloader = FileDownloadService.FileDownloader.getInstance(downloadRequest, listener);
downloader.download(context);
```

Also you can use (if required)
FileUtils.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.File;

public class FileUtils {

    public static File getDataDir(Context context) {

        String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/SampleZip";

        File file = new File(path);

        if(!file.exists()) {

            file.mkdirs();
        }

        return file;
    }

    public static File getDataDir(Context context, String folder) {

        String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + folder;

        File file = new File(path);

        if(!file.exists()) {

            file.mkdirs();
        }

        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me can you help

Comment: your code,but its not showing in sdcard and not able to download

Comment: can you paste full code please..i want to download zip file and store it in sdcard

Comment: @albert No one can write FULL CODE for you. You need to learn debugging.

Comment: i did all that permission

Comment: Working perfectly!

Comment: excellent Working perfectly!!!

Answer (score 5):

As JoxTraex said: the error is really obvious.

In `UnzipManager` line 129 you try to open a file that is not there. Thats why you get a `FileNotFoundException`. You should check your zip file if it is a correct one and can be extracted correctly on your PC.

Try to debug, too. Add a break point on that line and let the application debug and watch what happens there when the specific file location appears.

Comment: Who ever down voted: Without a comment, the down vote is nonsense. Thanks for not taking part in the community!

Comment: Your code worked fine. I just added the permission to the Manifest File. Its a great peace of code. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @BadLuckBrian spammer? Which code? Which permission?

Comment: The code in the question. It worked fine for me after i gave the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @BadLuckBrian The code in the question is not my code. I am taking back the "spammer" but I was highly confused by your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't Delete the file if exists (because the files will be overwritten) or instantiate innerFile again.

```
if (innerFile.exists()) {
         Log.d("DEBUG",
               "The Entry already exits!, so deleting..");
         innerFile.delete();
}

//Instantiate Again
innerFile = new File(innerFileName);
```

Deleting innerFile you lose the file and when trying to create directory using innerFile causes the FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code using the [performance improvement answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504692/2879783), it decompressed a 23 MB file into a 130 MB folder in exactly 1 minute:

```
public class Decompress {
private String _zipFile;
private String _location;

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
    _zipFile = zipFile;
    _location = location;

    _dirChecker("");
}

public void unzip() {
    try  {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

        byte b[] = new byte[1024];

        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());

                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(zin);
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);

                int n;
                while ((n = in.read(b,0,1024)) >= 0) {
                    out.write(b,0,n);
                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                out.close();
            }

        }
        zin.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

}

private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(_location + dir);

    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}}
```