# java.io.FileNotFoundException occuring while unzipping in android

Tags: java, android, java-io

I am trying to unzip  a zip file. This file contains several other files.The method I am using is:

```
private void unzipFile(String inputFileName,String outputDirName){
    int dataCount=0;
    byte[] dataArr=null;
    File inputZipFile=null,targetDir=null,unzipFile=null;
    ZipInputStream zipIPStream=null;
    ZipEntry zipEntry=null;
    BufferedOutputStream bfrOPStream=null;
    FileOutputStream unzipOPStream=null;
    try{
        inputZipFile=new File(inputFileName);
        targetDir=new File(outputDirName);
        zipIPStream=new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputZipFile)));
        while((zipEntry=zipIPStream.getNextEntry())!=null){
            dataArr=new byte[2048];
            // zipEntry=zipIPStream.getNextEntry();
            System.out.println("ZipEntry:"+zipEntry.getName());
            unzipFile=new File(targetDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+zipEntry.getName());
            System.out.println("Checking the path:"+unzipFile.getPath());
            if(!unzipFile.getParentFile().exists()){
                unzipFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            unzipOPStream=new FileOutputStream(targetDir.getPath()+"/"+zipEntry.getName());
            bfrOPStream=new BufferedOutputStream(unzipOPStream,2048);
            while((dataCount=zipIPStream.read(dataArr,0,2048))!=-1){
             unzipOPStream.write(dataArr,0,dataCount);
            }
            unzipOPStream.flush();
            unzipOPStream.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(zipIPStream!=null){
            try{
                zipIPStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method is throwing the following error

```
10-22 13:33:09.896: W/System.err(446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/iR/testbook/Caterpillar-Insect-Animal-Macro-HD-600x375.jpg (Not a directory)
```

Comment: in which line the error occurs? it seems that it's trying to read this .jpg as a directory which is not correct..

Comment: it seems that a .jpg is not a directory.

Comment: I got the solution. I was trying to unzip the file in the same directory in which it was kept. I changed the directory and now method is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below link for download and extract zip files, it will solve your problem.

For Downloading Zip File:-

[Download Zip File](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521)

For Extract Zip File:-

[Extract Zip File](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

And see below link for more information to solve this problem.

[Download and Extract Zip File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324103/download-and-extract-zip-file-in-android)

And the zip file is make using winrar software only otherwise this will give you above error.

Comment: @RichaLaad Welcome Richa, it's my pleasure.

Comment: @RichaLaad if you have any query regarding android then tell me any time or you can also send your query on my mail id.

Comment: That would be great as I am at beginner level in android. Please provide the mail id where i can put my query.