# Download Zip file using volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to download a zip file using a get call through volley. For now I am able to download a file using :  [Download and Extract Zip File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324103/download-and-extract-zip-file-in-android).

I want to use volley library instead. How can I do it?

Answer (score -2):

This is how I download zip file using volley:

```
package basavaraj.com.myapplicationtwo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.Listener<byte[]>, ErrorListener {
    EditText eText;
    Button download, unzip;
    boolean flag = false;
    private static Random random = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mycatalog";
    String zipFile;

    InputStreamVolleyRequest request;
    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
        unzip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unzip);
        download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*DownloadMapAsync mew = new DownloadMapAsync();
                mew.execute("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwxIiPT46CGHMWFTX0o4bzMzYU0");*/
                String mUrl="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwxIiPT46CGHMWFTX0o4bzMzYU0";
                request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, mUrl, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, null);
                RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),
                        new HurlStack());
                mRequestQueue.add(request);
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Zip File..");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        });
        unzip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*if (flag) {*/
                    try {
                        unzip();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            if (response!=null) {

                //Read file name from headers
                String content =request.responseHeaders.get("Content-Disposition")
                        .toString();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(content, "=");
                /*String arrTag = st.toString();

                String filename = arrTag;*/
                String filename = content.split("'")[2];
                filename = filename.replace(":", ".");
                Log.d("DEBUG::RESUME FILE NAME", filename);

                try{
                    long lenghtOfFile = response.length;

                    //covert reponse to input stream
                    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
                    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File(path, filename);
                    zipFile = file.toString();
                    map.put("resume_path", file.toString());
                    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE. ERROR:: "+error.getMessage());
    }

    public void unzip() throws IOException {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...Extracting zip file ... ");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        new UnZipTask().execute(zipFile, unzipLocation);
    }


    private class UnZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            String filePath = params[0];
            String destinationPath = params[1];

            File archive = new File(filePath);
            try {


                ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
                for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries();
                     e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                    unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, destinationPath);
                }


                UnzipUtil d = new UnzipUtil(zipFile, unzipLocation);
                d.unzip();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }


        private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry,
                                String outputDir) throws IOException {

            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
                return;
            }

            File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
            if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
            }

            // Log.v("", "Extracting: " + entry);
            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
            BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

            try {

            } finally {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();


            }
        }

        private void createDir(File dir) {
            if (dir.exists()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can not create dir " + dir);
            }
        }
    }


}



UnzipUtil.java


package basavaraj.com.myapplicationtwo;
import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream; 


public class UnzipUtil { 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location; 

  public UnzipUtil(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location; 

    _dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
       //   for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
         //   fout.write(c); 


            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
             int len;
             while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 fout.write(buffer, 0, len);
             }
             fout.close();

        //  } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
         // fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(_location + dir); 

    if(f.isDirectory()) {
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
} 



InputStreamVolleyRequest.java


    package basavaraj.com.myapplicationtwo;

    /**
     * Created by VISHAL on 4/5/2017.
     */

    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;


    public class InputStreamVolleyRequest extends Request<byte[]> {
        private final Response.Listener<byte[]> mListener;
        private Map<String, String> mParams;
        //create a static map for directly accessing headers
        public Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

        public InputStreamVolleyRequest(int post, String mUrl, Response.Listener<byte[]> listener,
                                        Response.ErrorListener errorListener, HashMap<String, String> params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            super(post, mUrl, errorListener);
            // this request would never use cache.
            setShouldCache(false);
            mListener = listener;
            mParams = params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            return mParams;
        }

        ;


        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(byte[] response) {
            mListener.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<byte[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            //Initialise local responseHeaders map with response headers received
            responseHeaders = response.headers;

            //Pass the response data here
            return Response.success(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    }
```