# Android how to speed up reading from a file to create Java objects using Buffered Input/Output?

Tags: java, android

I have this method that takes a json file from storage and turns it into a bunch of java objects. How do I add bufferred output/input streams in order to speed it up? Or is there another way to optimize the speed?

***EDIT: Im not only going to use this for reading from JSON files, so I dont need json to java parsers, I actually need to speed up file oprations using buffers :)***

```
public static ArrayList<String> convertJSONtoArrayList(File jsonStrings) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(jsonStrings);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertJSONtoArrayList(fileInputStream);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> convertJSONtoArrayList(InputStream fileInputStream) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ArrayList<String> arrayListString = new ArrayList<String>();

        int ctr;
        try {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                ctr = fileInputStream.read();
                while (ctr != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
                    ctr = fileInputStream.read();
                }
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of
            // json.
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
            int arrayLength = jsonArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayListString.add(jsonObject.getString(Tags.VALUE));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayListString;
    }
```

My idea for this being possible comes from here: [How to speed up unzipping time in Java / Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504291/how-to-speed-up-unzipping-time-in-java-android)  - in the answers becomes clear that if BufferedInputStream is added, the operation is sped up really good.

Comment: Did you check that file reading is your bottleneck? Are you sure you need to optimize this? Why just don't show a "Loading" dialog? This smells premature optimization.

Comment: Well I read 10 files and turn them into arraylists and hashmaps and these operations take a lot of time (10-20 seconds) but Im not exactly sure where the problem is

Comment: 10-20 seconds might not be a lot of time depending on files size. Anyway if the files are independent, consider threading the readings.

Comment: readings happen in an asynctask, are you suggesting I open a separate thread for each file simultaneously? How do I do that? Also, isnt Buffering going to solve this>?

Comment: In any case I suggest you first spot where the problem happens, then try to find a solution. Optimizing the wrong part will lead you nowhere. Use Android DDMS for checking which methods take most of the time.

Comment: I mean one thread per file, yes. How you're going to do that is your problem, but it doesn't look very hard (one AsyncTask per file instead of all files, how hard can it be?). Also please note [AsyncTask isn't really multi-threading](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/).

Comment: @J.Kowalski To truly multi-thread an `AsyncTask`, you want to look into using [`executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<String> convertJSONtoArrayList(File f) {
    final StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder(500);
    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String s;
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(s);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString.toString());
        int arrayLength = jsonArray.length();
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(arrayLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            result.add(jsonObject.getString(Tags.VALUE));
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

or try this (shoule be faster):

```
public static List<String> convertJSONtoArrayList(File f) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(f.length());
    try {
        ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(new FileInputStream(f));
        channel.read(buffer);
        channel.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final String jsonString = new String(buffer.array());

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        int arrayLength = jsonArray.length();
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(arrayLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            result.add(jsonObject.getString(Tags.VALUE));
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I need the method to accept an InputStream, will that change anything?

Comment: no, you just write ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(someInputStream);

Comment: but then what do I do here: ByteBuffer.allocate(f.length()); as I dont have f

Comment: I tried with a random value of 1500 but then I got a jsonerror about unexpected end of file at character 1500

Comment: no, you have to specify exactly or more value of your json file length. otherwise only a part of file will be red. That's why i've created in param as File object.

Comment: I dont know how to get the size from the inputstream, so I tried the first of the two solution, which works fast enough! thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Use the same code but wrap a BufferedInputStream around the FileInputStream.

Comment: well my question was how to do the wrapping, actually

Comment: 'new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(...))' seems pretty obvious to me.